# Simple "WHERE" query gone wrong

Tags: postgresql

I am having trouble creating a new column within a materialized view. I am trying to create this column so that when a row = "Average" within the expected clickthrough rate column it will return the calculation of how many impressions there are within that row.  As far as I can see everything is set up accordingly.  I am however getting the  following error message.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "clickthrough"
LINE 2: SELECT SUM("Impressions" * 1 ) WHERE Expected clickthrough r...
                                                  ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "clickthrough"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 94
```

It appears to me that any different variation that I make here ends up in a similar error message.

Does anyone know a solution to this one?  Is the entire query wrong?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW adwords_calculated AS
SELECT SUM("Impressions" * 1 ) WHERE Expected clickthrough rate = "Average" 
AS Average Clickthrough Rate   
from adwords_initial;
```

Current Columns

```
Impressions| Expected clickthrough rate
-----------+----------------------------
1          |--
66         |--
12         |Average
13         |--
1000       |Above Average
45         |Average
4          |Below Average
```

Desire Result

```
Impressions| Expected clickthrough rate |Average Clickthrough Rate
-----------+----------------------------+-----------------
1          |--                          |0
66         |--                          |0
12         |Average                     |12
13         |--                          |0
1000       |Above Average               |0
45         |Average                     |45
4          |Below Average               |0
```

Final result, (additional columns added per request in the comments.

```
Impressions| Expected clickthrough rate |Average CTR| Country
-----------+----------------------------+-----------+----------
1          |--                          |0          |USA 
66         |--                          |0          |Germany
12         |Average                     |12         |Austria
13         |--                          |0          |UK
1000       |Above Average               |0          |China
45         |Average                     |45         |USA
4          |Below Average               |0          |Germany
```

Comment: You sure about that column name? If it really contains spaces, you need to quote it in your query.

Comment: I have tried that as well, it reverts to an error message stating that here is then something wrong with the multiplication sign. Does the query look alright to you?  Thanks

Comment: No, does not look alright to me, but without your DDL and some sample data, I cannot help your further.

Comment: just a second please

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need column names like that, you must escape them with double quotes. String literals must be enclosed in single quotes. Also, the order of clauses is wrong. It should be

```
SELECT expression AS alias
FROM table
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Ok, That makes sense.  What if however I need to add other columns to the materialized view?  Is there a way to make the rows line up accordingly?

Comment: You can create a materialized view from any SQL query. What do you mean with "line up the rows"?

Comment: I am going to add in other columns into this materialized view that then have to line up accordingly.  I will provide an example up top.

Comment: I am basically trying to do an create/select within the materialized view.  My concern with your query is that I will have to insert/select the column "country" through another statement.  Won't this create a problem in regards to the rows matching correctly within separately selected columns?

Comment: A materialized view must be created with a single `SELECT` statement. To change the columns you must drop an recreate it. Base the materialized view on a query with a join.

Comment: Is it possible to select more columns within the query you provided?

Comment: Yes. You can have several expressions in the `SELECT` list, separated with comma. You can have several tables in the `FROM` list if you join them properly.

Comment: Would you mind providing a quick example based on the columns I have?  Thanks

Comment: I can't, because you didn't show the table definitions and how the tables should be joined. Anyway, first compose a query that produces the output you need, and use that to define a materialized view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44914262/creating-computed-columns-create-a-view

Comment: I don't see a single `CREATE TABLE` in that question. Besides, I don't understand how the "desired result" and "final result" in your question is produced.